# ¿cómo descargar varios archivos en asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy realizando un ejemplo de como descargar un archivo en `asp.net mvc` trayendolo desde la base de datos y funciona correctamente.
Ahora deseo descargar varios archivos a la vez.

Script

```
public FileResult Descargar(int id)
        {
            var files = bd.ArchivoProducto.Where(x=>x.idProducto==id);
            byte[] data = null;
            string contentType =null;
            string filename = null;
            //Lista de archivos que deseo descargar
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                data = file.datoArchivo;
                contentType = file.contentType;
                filename = file.nombreArchivo;
            }
            //¿Cómo descargarlos?
            return File(data, contentType, filename);
        }
```

Mi clase Archivo Producto

```
public class ArchivoProducto
{
    public int idArchivo { get; set; }
    public string nombreArchivo { get; set; }
    public byte[] datoArchivo { get; set; }
    public string contentType { get; set; }
    public int idProducto { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré la solución. Viendo uno de los videos de @gavilanch de youtube muestra un ejemplo claro de como guardar una lista de archivos bytes en un comprimido zip.

```
public FileResult Descargar(int id)
        {
            
            var files = bd.ArchivoProducto.Where(x=>x.idProducto==id);
            byte[] data = null;
            string filename = null;
            
            using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    filename = file.nombreArchivo;
                    data = file.datoArchivo;
                    zip.AddEntry(filename, data);
                }

                var nombreZip = "archivos.zip";
                using(MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(output);
                    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", nombreZip);
                }
            }

        }
```